# Should I use 16.04 LTS for a dual-core Celeron?

Tags: system-installation, 16.04

I'm completely new to Linux and I'm running this laptop [satellite-c50-b-14z](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/discontinued-products/satellite-c50-b-14z/)

I'd like to know if my laptop's Ubuntu 16.04 LTS-ready or which other version should I use (I guess the dual boot machine I'd like to make means no difference! :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't answer it for sure, but I can tell you it runs fine on my 12 years old Satellite which less powerful specs.

Comment: Should work fine. You could always try a life USB before settling....

Answer (score 1):

Even though the Intel Celeron N2840 processor with 2,16 Ghz is not the fastest processor at all, the TOSHIBA SATELLITE C50-B-14Z notebook is absolutely ready to run fine with Ubuntu 16.04. Most important is that the machine has 4 GB RAM and this is enough for running Ubuntu 16.04 with the standard Unity desktop environment and every other available desktop environment.
When it runs with Windows 8.1, which was pre-installed, it will run with Ubuntu even better ...